# Printing emails from json objects with php

Tags: php, json, email

I am trying to simply write all of these emails in a text file seperated with a comma like so

`email1@email.com, email2@email.com, etc`

I am new to php and now sure why I keep getting this parse error. I tried many things with all fails. Please help

```
<?php
$s = '{
  "-KNWTldOkA_WkT50a_aS" : {
    "Email" : "user@test.com",
    "num" : 3

  },
  "-KNi22_ZC7PlnDJkR4px" : {
    "Email" : "userEmailx@gmail.com",
    "num" : 10

  }
}';

$j = json_decode($s, true);
echo $j['-KNWTldOkA_WkT50a_aS']['Email'] . ',';

$file = fopen("emails.txt","w");

foreach ($j as $a) {
    var email = $a['Email'] . ',';
    fwrite($file, email);
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: what is the value of $j ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had several syntax errors in your code.

The correct code is:

```
<?php

$s = '{
     "-KNWTldOkA_WkT50a_aS" : {
     "Email" : "personsemail@gmail.com",
     "id" : 3
 },
   "-KNi22_ZC7PlnDJkR4px" : {
   "Email" : "personsemail@gmail.com",
   "id" : 10
 }
}';


$j = json_decode($s,True);

$emails = array();
foreach ($j as $a) {
    $emails[] = $a['Email'];
}
$file = fopen( __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ."emails.txt","w");
fwrite($file, implode(',', $emails ));
fclose($file);

?>
```

File emails.txt will be saved in the same directory as your php file with this code.

Comment: try write($file, implode("\n", $emails ));

Answer (score 1):

You will need to decode the json to a php array

```
$j = json_decode($s,True);
```

[php Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)